# Jquery: how to add commas to jquery.html() result

Tags: jquery

Below is the table structure I have -

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="file-uploader"> <span class="file-name">No File Selected</span>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="file-uploader"> <span class="file-name">abc.jpg</span>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="file-uploader"> <span class="file-name">No File Selected</span>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="file-uploader"> <span class="file-name">def.png</span>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="file-uploader"> <span class="file-name">xyz.gif</span>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I will get this html using

```
 var uploaded_file_content = $("#content").html();
```

In the result obtained from the above variable, I want to search for the file names with comma separated values that are associated with each  in every row.

Currently I'm using this method to fetch the file names -

```
 $('<div>').html(uploaded_file_content).find(".file-name").text();
```

But this gives me the file names that are not comma separated. Please help me out for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just do:

```
var t = "";
$('<div>').html(uploaded_file_content).find(".file-name").each(function(){
    t+= $(this).text() + ",";  
});
t= t.substring(0, t.length - 1);
```

This way t will contain all values as a commaseperated string.

Comment: $('<div>').html(uploaded_file_content).find(".file-name") will not return me an array to use each() function. It is a string.

Comment: find returns a jQuery object. And since there are multiple ".file-name" items in your html, you should be able to use the each function on it. The each will simply go through all the items that are found with the class. So this should work (even if there is only 1 result) (for more info check http://api.jquery.com/each/). If you are still having an issue, could you create a jsFiddle that reproduces your issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Make an array of all the names, and then use `join` to create a comma-separated string out of it.

```
var names = [];
$("#content .file-name").each(function() {
    names.push($(this).text());
}
var comma_separated_names = names.join(',');
```

Comment: But $("#content .file-name") is not an array to use each() function. Its a string.

Comment: `$("#content .file-name")` is a jQuery collection of all the elements matching the selector, not a string.

Comment: `$("#content .file-name")` not a string, it represent `spans` with class name `.file-name` in `#content`

Comment: yes i tried this also, it also seems to be working. thanks a lot :)